# SQL Selecting by parameter VS SQL Joining VS Saving in-memory Collection

Tags: c#, sql, database, performance, architecture

I am making a minor project to test out my skills and I stumbled across some questions I had in relation to many-to-many/reference relation tables, especially in terms of performance.

I attempted to create an ER-diagram to illustrate the relations (don't mind the ER arrow endings).
[image]

So the case is I want to find all the fines that a certain user has been fined. But what is the smartest solution in terms of load/performance? As I see it, I have a few options:

1. Create an InnerJoin statement to select the fines from a user, based of the reference table user_fines (not sure I would do this though, haha).
2. Create a query that would select fines based of user_fines where user_id is equal to user_fines.user_id
3. Store all the data in a collection (C# Model) and use lambda/linq to query the collections.

I assume 1 could be created smarter as a view to index?

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious... can a single fine be levied on two users such that they're both responsible for paying that one fine? In other words, does it make sense for one `Fine` record to be referenced by two `User_Fines` records with different `user_id` values?  If not, this could be reduced to 1:many: `User -|----|<- Fine` .

Comment: A great question @madreflection I thought about this too, but there would actually be a case where two users would be able to pay the same fine. However, you might be right that the setup with 1-* would be smarter.

Comment: Since you're testing your skills, here's an idea: implement the system using a `1:N` relationship for simplicity. Once you have that working -- ***BAM!*** -- requirement change. Modify the system to allow for multiple users to be levied the same fine. It doesn't get much more real-world than that.

Comment: @madreflection Sure! Will do, thank you!